# Matching two data frames with repeated keys in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to match two data frames based on their IDs and append the repeated selection into a single list.  Examples of the data frames I have are as below:

```
df1 = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), count = c(4, 6, 7, 8))
df2 = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), direction = c("up", "down", "up", "up"), reference = c(38, 39, 40, 40))
```

The two data frames look something like this:

| ID | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 7 |
| D | 8 |

| ID | direction | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | up | 38 |
| A | down | 39 |
| C | up | 40 |
| D | up | 40 |

Essentially, I want the final result to look like this, where the information from the df2 can be merged with df1 but with details concatenated into a single list and if multiple corresponding entries were found in df2, they can be stored as a list of lists:

| ID | count | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | c(up = 38, down = 39) |
| B | 6 | NA |
| C | 7 | c(up =40) |
| D | 8 | c(up =40) |

I have tried merging two data frames, but this will result in multiple entries repeated as a new row.  I'm considering trying to parse through the second data frame for a match as I did with the database environment previously, but I would appreciate it if you can let me know how to do such using data frame instead of environment.  Of course, if there's a more efficient approach to this, that would be much appreciated too! Example of what I did to match df1 onto a database environment:

```
i=1
for (row in 1:nrow(df)){
  tmp <- paste(df$ID[i])
  tmp2 <- as.list(mget(tmp, mirbaseID2ACC, ifnotfound = NA))
  if (is.na(tmp2) == TRUE) {
    tmp <- paste(df$simpleID[i])
    tmp2 <- as.list(mget(tmp, mirbaseID2ACC, ifnotfound = NA))
  }
  if (i<(nrow(df)+1)) {
    df$ACCESSION[i] <- tmp2
    i=i+1
  }
}
```

*Note that the "simple" column is there for the actual data frame because the samples have a very specific ID (ie A-ab-2) but for the purpose of this example, we can assume that the ID itself is simple enough to be detected with the data frame I'm trying to

Comment: Note that there's a typo in `df2 = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D")`. From your table, I guess it should be `df2 = data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "C", "D")`

Comment: @benson23 Oh, you're right.  Thank you for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `` `==` `` in `outer` then `apply` `which` as substitute for `match` which only matches once. Then subset `df2` on the found matches and cobble together using `paste` and `toString`.

```
r1 <- cbind(df1, info=sapply(apply(outer(df1$ID, df2$ID, `==`), 1, which), \(x) {
  if (!length(x) == 0)
    toString(Reduce(\(y, z) paste0(y, '=', z), df2[x, -1]))
  else NA
}))
r1
#   ID count           info
# 1  A     4 up=38, down=39
# 2  B     6           <NA>
# 3  C     7          up=40
# 4  D     8          up=40
```

Or, to get the desired list column:

```
r2 <- cbind(df1, info=I(lapply(apply(outer(df1$ID, df2$ID, `==`), 1, which), \(x) {
  if (!length(x) == 0)
    Reduce(\(y, z) paste0(y, '=', z), df2[x, -1])
  else NA
})))
r2
#   ID count         info
# 1  A     4 up=38, d....
# 2  B     6           NA
# 3  C     7        up=40
# 4  D     8        up=40
```

where

```
r2$info
# [[1]]
# [1] "up=38"   "down=39"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "up=40"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "up=40"
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), count = c(4, 6, 7, 
8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "C", "D"), direction = c("up", 
"down", "up", "up"), reference = c(38, 39, 40, 40)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `group_by` the `ID` column, then `summarise` the `direction` and `reference` columns into a list (use `df3$info` to look at the list) and `left_join` with `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- left_join(df1, 
          df2 %>% 
            group_by(ID) %>% 
            summarize(info = list(paste(direction, "=", reference))), 
          by = "ID")

  ID count               info
1  A     4 up = 38, down = 39
2  B     6               NULL
3  C     7            up = 40
4  D     8            up = 40

df3$info
[[1]]
[1] "up = 38"   "down = 39"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] "up = 40"

[[4]]
[1] "up = 40"
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `merge` + `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
    reference ~ ID + count,
    merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE),
    c,
    na.action = na.pass
)
```

gives

```
  ID count reference
1  A     4    38, 39
2  B     6        NA
3  C     7        40
4  D     8        40
```